# Connection refuse android php server

Tags: android

In my application I want to post multiple images to server including audio and images ..
I'm using **MultipartEntity** but when I call post method I'm getting `HttpHostConnectionException: connection refused`

Here is my code:

```
MultipartEntity entity=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

String path="mnt/sdcard/TAUKY/PICTURE/IMAGE_20130507_170848.png";
File f = new File(path);

String audio_path="mnt/sdcard/TAUKY/SOUND/SOUND_20130513_185502.wav";

File f_auido=new File(audio_path);          
entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(f));           
entity.addPart("audio", new FileBody(f_auido));         
entity.addPart("taukyname", new StringBody("My tauky"));            
entity.addPart("userId", new StringBody("63"));

hpost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = htpclnt.execute(hpost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sucess"+response, 1000).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file. have you add Internet Permission or not.
and
test on real device.